# Large raster frequency table / counts

Tags: raster, gdal, r, frequency

I try to calculate the frequency/count of pixel values of a raster in R using freq().

```
library(raster)
RastSmall <- raster(nrow=70, ncol=70) 
RastBig   <- raster(nrow=7000, ncol=7000) 
set.seed(0)
RastSmall[] <- round(runif(1:ncell(r_hr), 1, 5))
RastBig[] <- round(runif(1:ncell(r_hr), 1, 5))

freq(RastSmall)
value    count
[1,]     1  6540000
[2,]     2 12150000
[3,]     3 12140000
[4,]     4 11720000
[5,]     5  6450000
```

However, it is a fairly large file and takes extremely long, i.e. up to hours. Is there a faster way in R?

```
system.time(freq(RastSmall))
  user  system elapsed 
  0.008   0.000   0.004 
system.time(freq(RastBig))
  user  system elapsed 
  40.484   0.964  41.445
```

Is there a way to speed this up? Alternatively can this be done in the command line using something like gdal tools?

However, it is a fairly large file and takes extremely long. Is there a faster way in R? Alternatively can this be done in the command line using something like gdal or AWK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [`pkstat`](http://www.nongnu.org/pktools/html/md_pkstat.html) from the [pktools](http://www.nongnu.org/pktools/) package to achieve this. Specifically, you will need to add the options `-hist` and set the number of bins (categories) using `-nbins`. For instance:

```
pkstat -i input.tif -hist -nbins 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Does pkstat also work without bins?

Comment: yes, it is just one option.

Comment: here the syntax to export it into a text file that can than be imported in R:

      pkstat -i input.tif -hist > counts.txt 2>&1